# A typescript mapped type where values depend on the key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a mapped type where each entry is either a key that extends a given union of strings with a value of type T1, or the key does NOT extend the union of strings and has a value of T2.

Example: `MyMappedType<K extends string>` is a type where if keys extend `K` their value must be a `number`; otherwise their value must be a `boolean`:

```
const foo: MyMappedType<'foo' | 'bar'> = {
  foo: 42,
  bar: 43,
  qux: true,
  quux: false
};
```

I tried this:

```
type MyMappedType<K extends string> = {
  [P in string]: P extends K ? number : boolean;
}

const x: MyMappedType<'foo' | 'bar'> = {
  foo: 42,
  bar: 43,
  qux: true,
  quux: false
}
```

But apparently, after doing `[P in string]`, P has lost its ability to fulfill the conditional clause `P extends K`, so all keys are expected to be booleans, meaning `foo` and `bar` fails with `TS2322: type number is not assignable to type boolean.`

So I try this:

```
type MyMappedType<K extends string> = {
  [P in K]?: number;
} & {
  [P in string]?: boolean;
}
```

But that also gives a

```
TS2322: Type {foo: number; bar: number; qux: true; quux: false; }
is not assignable to type  { [x: string]: boolean | undefined; } 
Property  foo  is incompatible with index signature.
Type  number  is not assignable to type  boolean | undefined
```

I suppose this is because the `foo` and `bar` properties both match `in K` and `in string`, so they must effectively be `number & boolean`.

I then, rather naively, tried this:

```
type MyMappedType<K extends string> = {
  [P in K]?: number;
} & {
  [P in Exclude<string, K>]?: boolean;
}
```

But that also doesn't work, because excluding a union of strings from the full string type is not possible, to create a type which is "any string except 'foo' or 'bar'".

Is it possible to create the type I'm after?

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible. There’s a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867 for it. See the linked q/a for various workarounds.